# D3: zoom and pan with rect drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I create complex Family Tree with d3, now it draw all rect's with name just fine, also rect dragging works and links between them work nicely and updated.

Now i need add zoom and pan to my tree, because it will be VERY big.

I try to do it this way:

```
var margin = {top: 100, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 1800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    boxWidth = 140,
    boxHeight = 50;
    boxHSpace = 200,
    boxVSpace = 70,
    links = [];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .attr("bgcolor", "#2c2c2c")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
    }))
   .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")    

    ;



var datas;

datas = setPositions(buildDataAssocArray(getData()));

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(d3.entries(datas))
   .enter()
    .append("g")
    ;


function dragmove(d) {
    var x = d3.event.x;
    var y = d3.event.y;

    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");

    datas[d.key].dx =d3.event.x;
    datas[d.key].dy =d3.event.y;
    link.attr("d", connect);
}

// Define drag beavior
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("drag", dragmove)
        .origin(function() {
            var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
                    return {x: t.translate[0], y: t.translate[1]};
                });

    node.call(drag)
     .on("click", click);

    var selected;
    function click(){       
       if(!selected){
         selected = this;
         d3.select(selected.childNodes[0]).style('stroke', 'white');
      } 
      else {
         d3.select(selected.childNodes[0]).style('stroke', 'black');
         selected = this;
         d3.select(selected.childNodes[0]).style('stroke', 'white');
      }
    }          

    node.append("rect")
        .attr("width", boxWidth)
        .attr("height", boxHeight)
        .attr("fill", "tan")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.value.x - 70; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - d.value.y - 40; })
        .style("cursor", "pointer");


    node.append("text")
        .attr("font-size", "16px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.value.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - d.value.y - 15; })
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.value.name; })
        .style("cursor", "pointer");


    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(getLinks())
       .enter()
        .insert("path", "g")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
        .attr("d", connect);

    function connect(d, i) {
        var dsx=d.source.dx ? d.source.dx:0;
        var dsy=d.source.dy ? d.source.dy:0;
        var dtx=d.target.dx ? d.target.dx:0;
        var dty=d.target.dy ? d.target.dy:0;
        return     "M" + (d.source.x + dsx) + "," + (height - d.source.y +dsy)
//                 + "V" + (height - (3*(d.source.y-dsy) + 4*(d.target.y - dty))/7)
                 + "V" + (height - (3*(d.source.y-dsy) + 4*(d.target.y - dty))/7)
                 + "H" + (d.target.x+dtx)
                 + "V" + (height - (d.target.y- dty));
    };
    function getLinks() {
        return links ;
    }


function setPositions(datas)
{
    var fams=getFamily();


        var x=200 ,y=100;

    fams.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {


        item.childs.forEach(function(child, i1, arr1) {
            console.log(child);
            datas[child].x = x;
            datas[child].y = y;
            links.push({"source" : datas[child], "target" : datas[item.husb]});
            links.push({"source" : datas[child], "target" : datas[item.wife]});
        });

        x+=50;
        y+=50;

        datas[item.husb].x = x-100;
        datas[item.husb].y = y+100;
        datas[item.wife].x = x+100;
        datas[item.wife].y = y+100;

        x+=50;
        y+=50;

    });

    return datas;
}


function getFamily() {
    return [
    {
        "husb":   "003",
        "wife":   "002",
        "childs": ["001"]
        },
    {
        "husb":   "005",
        "wife":   "004",
        "childs": ["002"]
    },
    {
        "husb":   "007",
        "wife":   "006",
        "childs": ["003"]
    },
    {
        "husb":   "012",
        "wife":   "013",
        "childs": ["006"]
    },
    {
        "husb":   "015",
        "wife":   "016",
        "childs": ["017"]
    },
];
}

function buildDataAssocArray(adatas) {
    var datas = adatas;
    var dArray = [];
    datas.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
                item.x=0;
                item.y=0;
        dArray[item.id] = item;
    });
    return dArray;
}

//console.log(buildDataAssocArray());

function getData() {
    return [
     {  
        "id" : "001",
        "name": "Алтунин Василий",
        "mother" : "002",
        "father" : "003",
        "child"  : null,
     },
    {
        "id" : "002",
        "name": "Алтунина Елена",
        "mother" : "004",
        "father" : "005",
        "child"  : "001",
    },
    {
        "id" : "003",
        "name": "Алтунин Владимир",
        "mother" : "006",
        "father" : "007",
        "child"  : "001",
    },
        {
        "id" : "004",
                "name": "Зайцева Лидия",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "002",
    },
        {
        "id" : "005",
                "name": "Зайцев Анатолий",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "002",
    },
        {
        "id" : "006",
                "name": "Алтунина Зинаида",
        "mother" : "013",
        "father" : "012",
        "child"  : "003",
    },
        {
        "id" : "007",
                "name": "Алтунин Иван",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "003",
    },
        {
        "id" : "012",
                "name": "Бурцев Иван",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "003",
    },
        {
        "id" : "013",
                "name": "Девятова Александра",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "003",
    },
        {
        "id" : "014",
                "name": "Наталия Зайцева",
        "mother" : "004",
        "father" : "005",
        "child"  : "000",
    },
        {
        "id" : "015",
                "name": "Александр Зайцев",
        "mother" : "004",
        "father" : "005",
        "child"  : "017",
    },
        {
        "id" : "016",
                "name": "Евгения Ануфриева",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "017",
    },
        {
        "id" : "017",
                "name": "Федор Зайцев",
        "mother" : "016",
        "father" : "015",
        "child"  : "000",
    },
   ];
};
```

Here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/6u0d80fn/)

Zoom and pan works just fine, but it seems blocks rect's dragging ability.

What  is possible wrong here?

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/od9zutrs/) without zoom and pan, but with dragging.

**SOLVED**:

Here working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/6u0d80fn/1/

You need just add:

`node.on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); });`

Comment: you cant pan the graph and drag the nodes at the same time.  You can do it with a keyboard shortcut. For example mouseclick for pan and ctrl with mouseclick for dragging nodes without pan the graph

Comment: Here demo https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708 tht show that is possible, but it did not work for me :(

Comment: @VasilijAltunin The solution using `stopPropagation` does work with your code.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanx alot, here working example - https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/6u0d80fn/1/

Answer (score 0):

As @GerardoFurtadosuggested i add `stopPropagation` to my code and all now works fine:

Here the code:

```
var margin = {top: 100, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 1800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    boxWidth = 140,
    boxHeight = 50;
    boxHSpace = 200,
    boxVSpace = 70,
    links = [];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .attr("bgcolor", "#2c2c2c")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
    }))
   .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")    

    ;



var datas;

datas = setPositions(buildDataAssocArray(getData()));

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(d3.entries(datas))
   .enter()
    .append("g")
    ;


function dragmove(d) {
    var x = d3.event.x;
    var y = d3.event.y;

    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");

    datas[d.key].dx =d3.event.x;
    datas[d.key].dy =d3.event.y;
    link.attr("d", connect);
}

// Define drag beavior
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("drag", dragmove)
        .origin(function() {
            var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
                    return {x: t.translate[0], y: t.translate[1]};
                });

    node.call(drag)
     .on("click", click);

    var selected;
    function click(){       
       if(!selected){
         selected = this;
         d3.select(selected.childNodes[0]).style('stroke', 'white');
      } 
      else {
         d3.select(selected.childNodes[0]).style('stroke', 'black');
         selected = this;
         d3.select(selected.childNodes[0]).style('stroke', 'white');
      }
    }          

    node.on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

    node.append("rect")
        .attr("width", boxWidth)
        .attr("height", boxHeight)
        .attr("fill", "tan")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.value.x - 70; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - d.value.y - 40; })
        .style("cursor", "pointer");


    node.append("text")
        .attr("font-size", "16px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.value.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - d.value.y - 15; })
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.value.name; })
        .style("cursor", "pointer");


    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(getLinks())
       .enter()
        .insert("path", "g")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
        .attr("d", connect);

    function connect(d, i) {
        var dsx=d.source.dx ? d.source.dx:0;
        var dsy=d.source.dy ? d.source.dy:0;
        var dtx=d.target.dx ? d.target.dx:0;
        var dty=d.target.dy ? d.target.dy:0;
        return     "M" + (d.source.x + dsx) + "," + (height - d.source.y +dsy)
//                 + "V" + (height - (3*(d.source.y-dsy) + 4*(d.target.y - dty))/7)
                 + "V" + (height - (3*(d.source.y-dsy) + 4*(d.target.y - dty))/7)
                 + "H" + (d.target.x+dtx)
                 + "V" + (height - (d.target.y- dty));
    };
    function getLinks() {
        return links ;
    }


function setPositions(datas)
{
    var fams=getFamily();


        var x=200 ,y=100;

    fams.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {


        item.childs.forEach(function(child, i1, arr1) {
            console.log(child);
            datas[child].x = x;
            datas[child].y = y;
            links.push({"source" : datas[child], "target" : datas[item.husb]});
            links.push({"source" : datas[child], "target" : datas[item.wife]});
        });

        x+=50;
        y+=50;

        datas[item.husb].x = x-100;
        datas[item.husb].y = y+100;
        datas[item.wife].x = x+100;
        datas[item.wife].y = y+100;

        x+=50;
        y+=50;

    });

    return datas;
}


function getFamily() {
    return [
    {
        "husb":   "003",
        "wife":   "002",
        "childs": ["001"]
        },
    {
        "husb":   "005",
        "wife":   "004",
        "childs": ["002"]
    },
    {
        "husb":   "007",
        "wife":   "006",
        "childs": ["003"]
    },
    {
        "husb":   "012",
        "wife":   "013",
        "childs": ["006"]
    },
    {
        "husb":   "015",
        "wife":   "016",
        "childs": ["017"]
    },
];
}

function buildDataAssocArray(adatas) {
    var datas = adatas;
    var dArray = [];
    datas.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
                item.x=0;
                item.y=0;
        dArray[item.id] = item;
    });
    return dArray;
}

//console.log(buildDataAssocArray());

function getData() {
    return [
     {  
        "id" : "001",
        "name": "Алтунин Василий",
        "mother" : "002",
        "father" : "003",
        "child"  : null,
     },
    {
        "id" : "002",
        "name": "Алтунина Елена",
        "mother" : "004",
        "father" : "005",
        "child"  : "001",
    },
    {
        "id" : "003",
        "name": "Алтунин Владимир",
        "mother" : "006",
        "father" : "007",
        "child"  : "001",
    },
        {
        "id" : "004",
                "name": "Зайцева Лидия",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "002",
    },
        {
        "id" : "005",
                "name": "Зайцев Анатолий",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "002",
    },
        {
        "id" : "006",
                "name": "Алтунина Зинаида",
        "mother" : "013",
        "father" : "012",
        "child"  : "003",
    },
        {
        "id" : "007",
                "name": "Алтунин Иван",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "003",
    },
        {
        "id" : "012",
                "name": "Бурцев Иван",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "003",
    },
        {
        "id" : "013",
                "name": "Девятова Александра",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "003",
    },
        {
        "id" : "014",
                "name": "Наталия Зайцева",
        "mother" : "004",
        "father" : "005",
        "child"  : "000",
    },
        {
        "id" : "015",
                "name": "Александр Зайцев",
        "mother" : "004",
        "father" : "005",
        "child"  : "017",
    },
        {
        "id" : "016",
                "name": "Евгения Ануфриева",
        "mother" : null,
        "father" : null,
        "child"  : "017",
    },
        {
        "id" : "017",
                "name": "Федор Зайцев",
        "mother" : "016",
        "father" : "015",
        "child"  : "000",
    },
   ];
};
```

and [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/6u0d80fn/1/)