# D3.js v4 Separate Drag and Zoom/Pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

I have code that draws a square and plots points inside a canvas element. I use a d3.drag function to drag the square separate from the points and a d3.zoom function to zoom on BOTH the points and the square as well as pan both. The problem I'm having is two-fold:

1. Once zoomed, I sort of lose the ability to drag the square. Sort of in the sense that if you click around enough (typically the original spot of the square, not current), you can grab the square again.
2. Once I am able to grab the square again, the zoom renders to the very original zoom layer, not the current zoom.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiaramdelucia/ud27evu0/49/)

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619153/d3-zoom-and-pan-with-rect-drag) that recommends adding:

`square.on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); });`

but have not had any luck.

TIA

Comment: I am the one that advised OP in the linked question to use `stopPropagation`. However, that solution depends on the case... That being said, what you're seeing right now is the expected behaviour. This answer of mine explains what is happening and may help you to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46423884/5768908

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for pointing me to that that post. I do want to keep the zoom and pan functionality on the entire canvas. I want [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) functionality. I know that that is in v3 and the change on zoom in v4 consumes all the listening events, but is there a way to achieve that functionality in v4?